# Dashboard has been removed in Sonarqube 6.X?

Tags: sonarqube

In current LTS version you can configure the *Home* dashboard and *Custom* dashboards for projects, but in 6.3.1 (latest) the menu option doesn't appear. Are these features removed?

Is there any way to configure sonarqube home page, projects home page or add custom dashboards?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in release notes for [6.2](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+6.2+Upgrade+Notes):

> Customisable global dashboards and widgets are removed ( SONAR-8354 - Remove dashboards & widgets Closed ). As a consequence, custom plugins which were contributing widgets or dashboards won't be effective any more (but they won't fail SonarQube startup, they will just be ignored).